# Which info can be used from Person/Group column/field like $person.email or $person.title?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, json-formatting

I'm formatting a list for an org. chart-ish view and formatting the list JSON.

I use the person field to extract some information directly from the "User".
E.g. the users email address to display the email of that contact (with `$person.email`) or the name (with `$person.title`).

Is there a list of information which can be extracted / used from this person object?

I didn't find on the internet.

Tested some terms, but nothing but `.id` worked.

I'm thinking of work phone or something.

Any ideas?

[image]

```
"children": [
          {
            "elmType": "a",
            "style": {
              "cursor": "pointer"
            },
            "attributes": {
              "class": "ms-fontColor-red",
              "iconName": "Mail",
              "href": "='mailto:' + [$User.email] + '?body=Dear ' + [$User.title] + ',\r\n'",
              "title": "='E-Mail an ' + [$User.title]"
            }
          }
        ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get following properties from the people field in JSON formatting (with example values):

```
{
   "id": "122",
   "title": "Kalya Tucker",
   "email": "kaylat@contoso.com",
   "sip": "kaylat@contoso.com",
   "picture": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/kaylat_contoso_com_MThumb.jpg?t=63576928822",
   "department":"Human Resources",
   "jobTitle":"HR Manager"
}
```

**Official documentation**:

[Column Formatting in SharePoint - Special string values](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#special-string-values) - Check **People fields** section